# Why is the !! preferable in checking if an object is true?

Tags: javascript

Some JavaScript examples use `!!` to check if an object is available

```
// Check to see if Web Workers are supported
if (!!window.Worker) {
  // Yes, I can delegate the boring stuff!
}
```

Why is this preferred to just `if (window,Worker)` and in what context would this fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It isn't preferable, or even different, in this case.** The double-bang converts the variable that follows it into a Boolean value (similar to wrapping in the `Boolean()` constructor). Gets around potential problems with truthy and falsey variables.

However, putting the variable alone in an `if()` clause does the same thing (it also resolves the contents of the `if`'s parens to a hard Boolean).

**The double-bang can prove helpful in other cases,** such as if you want to return a `true` or `false` at the end of a function based on a variable's truthiness/falsiness. That would be rather than:

```
if(condition) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You could simply write:

```
return !!condition;
```

Comment: The rules for truthiness for ! and for `if` are the same.

Comment: You are right! I'll amend my answer presently.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.

`!!` is useful when you are passing an object into a function that (like jQuery's `toggle()`) checks to see if its argument is a boolean, or when the function might stash its argument and thereby prevent the object from being collected.

The case you cite is neither of those.  Use a bare `if`.

Answer (score 1):

In the condition of an if statement both versions will do the same thing and its a stylistic choice. Some people prefer use `!!` to highlight that Worker is not a boolean and is being converted tto boolean.

Comment: I think a six-year-old child understands that the thing after the word "if" is to be interpreted as true or false.  `!!` is just showing off.

Comment: @Malvolio: The purpose of the `!!` is to make the reader aware that the argument *isn't* a Boolean value, but is being coerced into one.

Comment: @supercat -- it would certainly have that effect, but why would the reader care?

Comment: @Malvolio: A reader who sees `if (woozle(x,y))...` and also sees `fnord = woozle(x,y);`, might expect that `fnord` would be given a true/false value.  Changing the code to `if (!!woozle(x,y))` would suggest to the reader that `woozle` is probably returning something other than a true/false value, and thus avoid creating any false expectations about `fnord = woozle(x,y);`.

Comment: @supercat -- I think your reasoning is sound but your assertions are in error.  Far more programmers know how the `if` statement works than know what `!!` means.  In fact, I would doubt that there are more than a handful of Javascript programmers in the whole world who instinctively assume that the argument to the if statement should be a boolean but have a clue what bang-bang does.

Comment: @Malvolio: What I was originally saying when I wrote this answer is that the `!!` can be used to mitigate the fact that Javascript is dynamically typed and does not have type annotations. This has nothing to do with how the if statement works.